# Property/Accessor ambiguity when using Expression Body operators

Tags: c#, .net, properties, operators

Using C# (.Net 4.6), assuming this code:

```
public class test
{
    private bool _a = true;

    public test() { }

    public bool a => _a;
}
```

Is the `public bool a => _a;` implementation the same as:

```
public bool a { get => _a; }
```

or:

```
public bool a
{
    get => _a;
    set => _a = value;
}
```

?

Which is to say, if using the single expression body declaration on an Property/Accessor (as opposed to declaring both *get* and *set* separately) is the resulting functionality read/write, or read-only?

I tried looking through Microsoft's help (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) but it only mentioned expression bodies in *one sentence* and wasn't at all clear about the differences.

Comment: Why not use `public bool a { get; }` if you want a readonly property?

Comment: @vc74 I don't necessarily *want* just a read-only property; the example here was intentionally highly simplified. What I wanted to know, *with certainty,* was which way this syntax is managed by the compiler so I could use it whenever I wanted the functionality that it provides, and *not* use it improperly.

Comment: OK then, `public bool a => _a;` gives you the ability to modify `a` internally (in the class's code) but it's readonly for the outside, so it's equivalent to `public bool a { get { return a; } }` (no set accessor)

Comment: If it "gives you the ability to *modify a internally (in the class's code)* but it's readonly for the outside", wouldn't that be ```public bool a { get => _a; private set => _a = value; }``` ??

Comment: No, with `public bool a => _a` even within your class, you won't be able to do `a = false` (you can of course use `_a = false`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just have the `get` accessor only. So this:

```
public bool a => _a;
```

Will be evaluated to this:

```
public bool a
{
    get
    {
        return _a;
    }
}
```

You can find the intermediate steps and results of your code compilation here in [SharpLap](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxAvsi0smpjOgC4CmAZx7ICSYugAOAJwCWANwCG/dACMA9moA26APoL0AXl5SArnwDcyRkU78hdfOjbWSqjdv0GAfLoWWkTEA)

Comment: Okay, but I have no idea what *"sharplab"* is -- I've literally *never* heard of it before now. Is it just a code cleaner? Is the interpretation that it provides genuinely authoritative, or is it merely speculative / suggestive? 

Comment: @NetXpert Yes, it is definitely invaluable! That's a handy resource! Otherwise I didn't reference it, you can search about it to find out more, it is a C#/VB/F# compiler playground which you can find the intermediate steps and results of your code compilation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool a => _a;
```

Implementation the same as:

```
public bool a { get => _a; }
```

And:

```
static bool _a = true;
public bool a { get; set; } = _a;
```

Implementation the same as:

```
public bool a
{
    get => _a;
    set => _a = value;
}
```